# Como escutar uma conexao Socket no Android

Tags: android, servidor, socket

Tenho um servidor socket tcp java no pc e um cliente socket tcp no android, consiguo receber dados do servidor. Porem como faço para criar um servidor que fique sempre escutando uma porta no android, ou seja criar um servidor socket no android. Posso por exemplo deixar uma thread apenas enviando dados para uma porta no pc, e outra thread apenas recebendo dados do pc e atualizando a ui? Alguem tem exemplos ou links para ajudar.

> // servidor sockert que recebe comandos do android
>
> package  tanio;
>
> import java.io.*; import java.net.*;
>
> import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
>
> class socketServer implements Runnable{
>                 String clientSentence = "";
>           String capitalizedSentence;
>
> ```
>     int porta = 9837;
>
>
>
>     public void run(){
>     /*atribuicao do numero da porta ao socket*/
>                     ServerSocket welcomeSocket = null;
>                   try {
>                       welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(porta);
>                   } catch (IOException e1) {
>                       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
>                       e1.printStackTrace();
>                   }
>                     System.out.println("Esperando conexoes na porta " + porta);
>
>                     {
>                     while (true) {
>    Socket connectionSocket = null;        try {           connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();      } catch (IOException e1) {          // TODO
> ```
>
> Auto-generated catch block            e1.printStackTrace();       }
>          System.out.println("Conexao aceita….");
>
> ```
>     BufferedReader inFromClient = null;       try {           inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
> ```
>
> connectionSocket.getInputStream() ));         } catch (IOException e1) {
>             // TODO Auto-generated catch block          e1.printStackTrace();       }
>            try {            DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream( connectionSocket.getOutputStream() );
>                     } catch (IOException e1) {          // TODO Auto-generated catch block          e1.printStackTrace();       }
>
> ```
>                               try {
>                                   DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream( connectionSocket.getOutputStream() );
>
>                                    clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
>
>                                    System.out.println("Frase recebida do Cliente: " + clientSentence);
>
>                                    //connectionSocket.close();
>
>
>
>
>                                    int valorconvertido = Integer.parseInt(clientSentence);
>                                    System.out.println(valorconvertido);
>
>                                    switch (valorconvertido){ 
>
>                                    case 2:
>
>                                        modoAutonomo executarmodoAutonomo = new modoAutonomo();
>                                        executarmodoAutonomo.execute();
>
>                                       outToClient.writeUTF("Ligando o Carro!");;
>                                       //outToClient.writeByte(2);
>                                       outToClient.flush();
>                                       //outToClient.close();
>
>                                        break;      
>
>                                    case 3:
>
>                                       desligar executardesligar = new desligar();
>                                       executardesligar.execute();
>
>                                        break;
>
>
>                                   }
>
>                                    connectionSocket.close();
>
>
>                                       } catch (Exception e) {
>                                               System.out.println("PERDA DA CONEXAO");
>                                       }
>                                       /*fecha a conexão aberta*/
>                                       try {
>                                           connectionSocket.close();
>                                       } catch (IOException e) {
>                                           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
>                                           e.printStackTrace();
>                                       }
>                                       System.out.println("Conexao fechada");
>                  }
>
>
>                } }    }
> ```

Metodo para ligar o carro

> package tanio;
>
> import javax.swing.ImageIcon; import javax.swing.JOptionPane; import
>   javax.swing.SwingWorker;
>
> import java.text.SimpleDateFormat; import java.util.Date; import
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
>
> import tanio.chamarTelaPrincipal;
>
> public class modoAutonomo extends SwingWorker  {
>             public SerialComLeitura arduino = new SerialComLeitura("COM7",9600, 0);
>       public char valorlido;
>       static int funcao;
>
> ```
>   protected Object doInBackground(){
>
>
>
>       arduino.enviarDados(2);
>       arduino.receberDados();
>
>       delay.delay(3000); 
>       char valorlido = arduino.getPeso().charAt(0);  
>
>
>       if (valorlido == 'b' | valorlido == 'c') {
>       arduino.FecharCom();
>
>           chamarTelaPrincipal.Info.setText("Chave Ligou!");
>
>
>
>           //chamarTelaPrincipal.jBLigar.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\alicia.cc\\Desktop\\start.jpg"));   
>           //chamarTelaPrincipal.jBLigar.setEnabled( false );
>           //chamarTelaPrincipal.jBLigar.setVisible(false);
>
>           //chamarTelaPrincipal.jBDesligar.setEnabled( true );
>           //chamarTelaPrincipal.jBDesligar.setVisible(true);
>
>
>
>            //arduino.FecharCom();
>               delay.delay(2000);
>               chamarTelaPrincipal.Info.setText("Acionando Partida!");
>
>           ////comando para ligar o carro
>
>           arduino.enviarDados(4);
>           arduino.receberDados();
>           delay.delay(2000);
>           char valorlido1 = arduino.getPeso().charAt(0);   //                 char valorlido1 = arduino.getPeso().charAt(0);  
>             if (valorlido1 == 'y' ){
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>               chamarTelaPrincipal.Info.setText("Carro Ligou!");
>
>
>
>               chamarTelaPrincipal.btnDesligar.setEnabled(true);//botao desligar
> ```
>
> fica ativado
>
> ```
>                 chamarTelaPrincipal.btnLigarMotor.setEnabled(false);//botao ligar fica
> ```
>
> desativado
>
> ```
>                 chamarTelaPrincipal.jBDesligar.setVisible(true); 
>                 chamarTelaPrincipal.jBDesligar.setEnabled(true); //botao desligar modo autonomo habilita
>
>
>                 chamarTelaPrincipal.jBLigar.setEnabled(false); // botao ligar modo autonomo desabilita
>                 chamarTelaPrincipal.jBLigar.setVisible(false);
>
>                 chamarTelaPrincipal.btnLigarResto.setEnabled(false); //botao ligar
> ```
>
> resto desativa
>                       chamarTelaPrincipal.btnLigarResto.setVisible(false);
>
> ```
>                 chamarTelaPrincipal.btnDesligarResto.setEnabled(false);// botao
> ```
>
> desligar resto desativa
>                       chamarTelaPrincipal.btnDesligarResto.setVisible(false);
>
> ```
>              arduino.FecharCom();
>
>
>               delay.delay(2000);
>
>               arduino.enviarDados(7);
>               arduino.receberDados();
>               delay.delay(2000); 
>
>               char valorlido9 = arduino.getPeso().charAt(0);  
>               if (valorlido9 == 'r') {
>                   // som ligou
>                   arduino.FecharCom();
>                   //chamarTelaPrincipal.btnsomon.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\alicia.cc\\Desktop\\somdesligado.jpg"));   
>
>
>                   chamarTelaPrincipal.btnsomon.setEnabled(false); 
>                   chamarTelaPrincipal.btnsomon.setVisible(false); 
>
>
>
>                   chamarTelaPrincipal.btnsomoff.setEnabled(true); 
>                   chamarTelaPrincipal.btnsomoff.setVisible(true); 
>
>                       chamarTelaPrincipal.Info.setText("Som Ligado!");    
>               }
>               else if(valorlido9 == 't'){
>                   //som ja estava ligado
>
>                   arduino.FecharCom();
>
>                   //chamarTelaPrincipal.btnsomon.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\alicia.cc\\Desktop\\somdesligado.jpg"));   
>
>                   chamarTelaPrincipal.btnsomon.setEnabled(false); 
>                   chamarTelaPrincipal.btnsomon.setVisible(false); 
>
>
>
>                   chamarTelaPrincipal.btnsomoff.setEnabled(true); 
>                   chamarTelaPrincipal.btnsomoff.setVisible(true); 
>
>
>                       chamarTelaPrincipal.Info.setText("Som Ja esta Ligado!");
>
>
>               }
>               else{
>                   System.out.println(valorlido9);
>
>                   arduino.FecharCom();
>                   //houve algum problema na conexao e o som nao ligou
>
>                   chamarTelaPrincipal.Info.setText("Problema na Conexao, Som nao ligou!");
>                       delay.delay(1000);
>                   chamarTelaPrincipal.Info.setText("Verifique o pino VoltSom!");
>
>               }
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>           delay.delay(2000);
>
>           arduino.enviarDados(5);
>           arduino.receberDados();
>           delay.delay(2000); 
>
>           char valorlido2 = arduino.getPeso().charAt(0);  
>           if (valorlido2 == 'j') {
>               arduino.FecharCom();
>
>               chamarTelaPrincipal.Info.setText("Potência Ligada");
>
>               //chamarTelaPrincipal.btnpotencia.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\alicia.cc\\Desktop\\onoff.jpg"));   
>
>               chamarTelaPrincipal.btnpotencia.setEnabled(false);
>               chamarTelaPrincipal.btnpotencia.setVisible(false);
>
>               chamarTelaPrincipal.btnpotenciaoff.setEnabled(true);
>               chamarTelaPrincipal.btnpotenciaoff.setVisible(true);
>
>
>
>
>               //chamarTelaPrincipal.jBLigar.setEnabled( false );
>               //chamarTelaPrincipal.jBDesligar.setEnabled( true );
>           }
>           else if (valorlido2 == 's'){
>               arduino.FecharCom();
>
>               chamarTelaPrincipal.Info.setText("Potencia Ja Esta Ligada!");
>
>               chamarTelaPrincipal.btnpotencia.setEnabled(false);
>               chamarTelaPrincipal.btnpotencia.setVisible(false);
>
>               chamarTelaPrincipal.btnpotenciaoff.setEnabled(true);
>               chamarTelaPrincipal.btnpotenciaoff.setVisible(true);
>
>
>
>           }
>           else {
>               arduino.FecharCom();
>
>               chamarTelaPrincipal.Info.setText("Houve algum problema na Conexao!");
>           }
>
>
>           delay.delay(2000);
>
>           Date hora = new Date();
>           Date minutos = new Date();
>           SimpleDateFormat formatarhora = new SimpleDateFormat("H");
>           SimpleDateFormat formatarminutos = new SimpleDateFormat("mm");
>           String horaformatada = formatarhora.format(hora);
>           String minutosformatada = formatarminutos.format(minutos);
>           //System.out.printf(horaformatada);
>           //System.out.printf(":%s", minutosformatada);
>           int horaint = Integer.parseInt(horaformatada);
>           int minutosint = Integer.parseInt(minutosformatada);
>
>           System.out.print(horaint);
>           System.out.println(minutosint);
>
>           if (horaint > 2 ){
>
>           arduino.enviarDados(11);
>           arduino.receberDados();
>           delay.delay(2000); 
>
>           char valorlido4 = arduino.getPeso().charAt(0);  
>           if (valorlido4 == 'j') {
>               System.out.println(valorlido);
>               arduino.FecharCom();
>
>               chamarTelaPrincipal.Info.setText("Farois de Milha Ligados");
>
>
>               //chamarTelaPrincipal.btnpotencia.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\alicia.cc\\Desktop\\onoff.jpg"));   
>
>               chamarTelaPrincipal.btnligarfarolmilha.setEnabled(false);
>               chamarTelaPrincipal.btnligarfarolmilha.setVisible(false);
>
>               chamarTelaPrincipal.btndesligarfarolmilha.setEnabled(true);
>               chamarTelaPrincipal.btndesligarfarolmilha.setVisible(true);
>
>
>               //chamarTelaPrincipal.jBLigar.setEnabled( false );
>               //chamarTelaPrincipal.jBDesligar.setEnabled( true );
>           }
>           else if(valorlido4 == 's'){
>               arduino.FecharCom();
>
>
>               chamarTelaPrincipal.Info.setText("Farois de Milha Ja Ligados");
>
>               //chamarTelaPrincipal.btnpotencia.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\alicia.cc\\Desktop\\onoff.jpg"));   
>
>               chamarTelaPrincipal.btnligarfarolmilha.setEnabled(false);
>               chamarTelaPrincipal.btnligarfarolmilha.setVisible(false);
>
>               chamarTelaPrincipal.btndesligarfarolmilha.setEnabled(true);
>               chamarTelaPrincipal.btndesligarfarolmilha.setVisible(true);
>
>
>               //chamarTelaPrincipal.btnpotencia.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\alicia.cc\\Desktop\\onoff.jpg"));
>               //chamarTelaPrincipal.btnpotencia.setEnabled(false);
>           }
>           else {
>               arduino.FecharCom();
>               chamarTelaPrincipal.Info.setText("Houve algum problema na Conexao!");
>
>           }
>           }
>
>
>
>
>             }
>              else if (valorlido1 == 'i'){
>                arduino.FecharCom();
>                   chamarTelaPrincipal.Info.setText("Não e Possivel dar Partida!");
>                   delay.delay(1000);
>                   chamarTelaPrincipal.Info.setText("Chave Desligada!");
>
>
>
>   chamarTelaPrincipal.btnDesligar.setEnabled(false);//botao desligar fica ativado
>
>                 chamarTelaPrincipal.btnLigarMotor.setEnabled(true);//botao ligar fica
> ```
>
> desativado
>
> ```
>                 chamarTelaPrincipal.btnDesligar.setEnabled(false);//botao ligar fica
> ```
>
> desativado
>
> ```
>                 chamarTelaPrincipal.jBDesligar.setVisible(false); 
>                 chamarTelaPrincipal.jBDesligar.setEnabled(false); //botao desligar modo autonomo habilita
>
>
>                 chamarTelaPrincipal.jBLigar.setEnabled(true); // botao ligar modo autonomo desabilita
>                 chamarTelaPrincipal.jBLigar.setVisible(true);
>
>                 chamarTelaPrincipal.btnLigarResto.setEnabled(false); //botao ligar
> ```
>
> resto desativa
>                       chamarTelaPrincipal.btnLigarResto.setVisible(false);
>
> ```
>                 chamarTelaPrincipal.btnDesligarResto.setEnabled(false);// botao
> ```
>
> desligar resto desativa
>                       chamarTelaPrincipal.btnDesligarResto.setVisible(false);
>
> ```
>               }
>               else if (valorlido1 == 'x'){
>               arduino.FecharCom();
>                   chamarTelaPrincipal.Info.setText("Não e possivel dar a Partida!");
>                   delay.delay(1500);
>                   chamarTelaPrincipal.Info.setText("Freio de mão não acionado!");
>
>
>                   chamarTelaPrincipal.btnDesligar.setEnabled(false);//botao desligar
> ```
>
> fica ativado
>
> ```
>                               chamarTelaPrincipal.btnLigarMotor.setEnabled(true);//botao ligar fica
> ```
>
> desativado
>
> ```
>                               chamarTelaPrincipal.btnDesligar.setEnabled(false);//botao ligar fica
> ```
>
> desativado
>
> ```
>                               chamarTelaPrincipal.jBDesligar.setVisible(false); 
>                               chamarTelaPrincipal.jBDesligar.setEnabled(false); //botao desligar
> ```
>
> modo autonomo habilita
>
> ```
>                               chamarTelaPrincipal.jBLigar.setEnabled(true); // botao ligar modo
> ```
>
> autonomo desabilita
>                                     chamarTelaPrincipal.jBLigar.setVisible(true);
>
> ```
>                               chamarTelaPrincipal.btnLigarResto.setEnabled(false); //botao ligar
> ```
>
> resto desativa
>                                     chamarTelaPrincipal.btnLigarResto.setVisible(false);
>
> ```
>                               chamarTelaPrincipal.btnDesligarResto.setEnabled(false);// botao
> ```
>
> desligar resto desativa
>                                     chamarTelaPrincipal.btnDesligarResto.setVisible(false);
>
> ```
>               }
>               else if(valorlido1 == 't'){
>                   arduino.FecharCom();
>                   chamarTelaPrincipal.Info.setText("Não e possivel dar a Partida!");
>                   delay.delay(1500);
>                   chamarTelaPrincipal.Info.setText("Marcha 1 Engatada!");
>
>
>
>                   chamarTelaPrincipal.btnDesligar.setEnabled(false);//botao desligar
> ```
>
> fica ativado
>
> ```
>                               chamarTelaPrincipal.btnLigarMotor.setEnabled(true);//botao ligar fica
> ```
>
> desativado
>
> ```
>                               chamarTelaPrincipal.btnDesligar.setEnabled(false);//botao ligar fica
> ```
>
> desativado
>
> ```
>                               chamarTelaPrincipal.jBDesligar.setVisible(false); 
>                               chamarTelaPrincipal.jBDesligar.setEnabled(false); //botao desligar
> ```
>
> modo autonomo habilita
>
> ```
>                               chamarTelaPrincipal.jBLigar.setEnabled(true); // botao ligar modo
> ```
>
> autonomo desabilita
>                                     chamarTelaPrincipal.jBLigar.setVisible(true);
>
> ```
>                               chamarTelaPrincipal.btnLigarResto.setEnabled(false); //botao ligar
> ```
>
> resto desativa
>                                     chamarTelaPrincipal.btnLigarResto.setVisible(false);
>
> ```
>                               chamarTelaPrincipal.btnDesligarResto.setEnabled(false);// botao
> ```
>
> desligar resto desativa
>                                     chamarTelaPrincipal.btnDesligarResto.setVisible(false);
>
> ```
>               }
>
>               else{
>                   arduino.FecharCom();
>                   chamarTelaPrincipal.Info.setText("Houve algum problema na Conexao!");
>               }
>       }
>
>       else {
>           arduino.FecharCom();
>           chamarTelaPrincipal.Info.setText("Houve algum problema na Conexao!");
>
>
>       }           return valorlido;
>   } }
> ```

```
Veja que aqui atualizo a gui do programa java e precisso tambem enviar um feedback para a aplicao android
```

> ```
>               chamarTelaPrincipal.Info.setText("Carro Ligou!");
>               // Preciso aqui um metodo para enviar a informacao para o  a    android
>
>
>               chamarTelaPrincipal.btnDesligar.setEnabled(true);//botao desligar
> ```
>
> fica ativado

Comment: Mas se você já tem um servidor no pc criado qual a necessidade de criar um para dispositivo android ?

Comment: Por exemplo. Envia um dado do android para o pc. No servidor socket no pc recebe esse valor e faz uma condicao, dentro de um switch verifica qual comando recebido e executa outro metodo. Durante a execucao desses metodos ele tem que enviar informacoes de volta para o android, vou colocar os codigo para voce dar uma olhada. Quando o metodo for chamado ele necessita enviar informações  de volta para o android, como eu poderia fazer isso?